# Trouble migrating WordPress from local server to host

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, import

I'm having trouble migrating a Wordpress site I've been working on from my local machine onto a host.

I've been through the documentation and as far as I understand, I have to:

1. Export the wordpress database from my local server.
2. Edit the wp-config.php file to suit my target server.
3. Change the URL's in the settings to suit my target server.
4. Import the database on my target server and move over the adjusted wordpress installation onto my target server.

I can do all of this, but my there seem to be some problems: in my hosts phpmyadmin I can't view or edit any users and neither can I create any databases (there's no option for it). When I try to import a database I get an error: #1046 - No database selected.

What do I not know/doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, on shared hosts you generally cannot create users or databases. This is usually because you only have a limited number of them, and so they are created elsewhere, after they've checked you've not exceeded your permitted maximum. You can often do this in cPanel or DirectAdmin, however. Also, if you already have a database, try adding `USE (databasename);` at the start of your locally exported data (in SQL format) - where `(databasename)` of course is the name of the db on your remote host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If importing a database, you need to create one first with the same name, then select it and then IMPORT the existing database to it.

Comment: I forgot that you can make databases outside of phpmyadmin. Okay, that's one issue down!

Answer (score 0):

> I can do all of this, but my there seem to be some problems: in my hosts phpmyadmin I can't view or edit any users and neither can I
>   create any databases (there's no option for it).

If you're going through CPanel, you won't be able to add a database directly through PHPMyadmin. You should go to your host's home page and look for some wizard to create a database. (it should be next to the PHPMyadmin link.

Alternatively, for moving wordpress, You can install wordpress on your live site, then [export](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen) your localhost content via Wordpress's dashboard and then [import](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content) it on the live site.

This article on [Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) will also be helpful.